# Update all records in a solr column to "hello"

Tags: solr

There are many of records in a solr collection. We need to update a particular column to "hello"

I have executed below json using update request handler, But it create a new record with primary key * and set its column to hello.

{
"Primary_key":"*",
"Column1":{"set":"hello"}
}

Is there any way to update a column1 in all records to hello?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to update a documents in Solr using a query like '*'.
According to me, the best way you can speed up your column update in this case is to submit multiple queries in single update request and use atomic updates.
Atomic updates allows changing only fields of a document without having to reindex the entire document.
You can send multiple update requests like,

```
    [{"id":"1",
     "column1":{"set":"hello"},
     {"id":"2",
     "column1":{"set":"hello"}]
```

There is a very old [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7490) with this respect.